# Error 500 while running WCF service on IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis, ksoap2

Maybe someone can help me.

I'm hosting WCF service on IIS. The .svc file is accessible from a browser. It works locally but when I publish on the server and I want to call a method from my client, I always got an HTTP Status 500 from the server.

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!-- Allow receiving of large files, maxRequestLength is in kB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="300" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServices.MVSWebServicesBehavior"
        name="WebServices.MVSWebServices">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebServices.MVSWebServices_I" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://<ipaddr>/WebServices/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebServices.MVSWebServicesBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The log file only shows me

`2013-06-17 13:55:44 <ipaddr> POST /WebServices/MVSWebServices.svc - 80 - <ipaddr> ksoap2-android/2.6.0+ 500 0 0 2121`

So I tried Failed Request Tracing on the server and I got (I can provide the full trace if necessary):

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName IsapiModule 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 500 
HttpReason Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

Four days I'm banging my head against walls, any help would be appreciated :)

PS: I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

Edit1:

After enabling WCF Tracing, there's the resulting error message:

```
The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/MVSWebService_I/getTimestamp' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and  receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that  sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
```

The contract mismatch make me think to verify the SOAP Action in WSDL file:

```
http://tempuri.org/MVSWebServices_I/getTimestamp
```

And then in my client (Android application):

```
http://tempuri.org/MVSWebService_I/getTimestamp
```

Just to spot a missing **s** in my action !! I added the missing letter to the SOAP action and everything worked well.
So that's it, this missing letter costed me 4 days but I still love programming :D

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe your deployment/publisching to the server is not correct. Why don't you monitor the IIS worker process that is executing your code for any errors using process monitor e.g., maybe on your server your code is missing some dll or resource.

Comment: Enable [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Comment: Make sure that you have .NET 4.0 installed on your server and as said by @CodeCaster enabled WCF tracing and inspect the trace file to see the exact reason for the 500 internal server error

Comment: I enabled WCF tracing and the error message allows me to find my mistake (see Edit1).

Answer (score 0):

Can you hit it if you run the browser on the server as opposed to running it locally trying to hit the server?

Comment: Wherever I am, I can hit the .svc file from a browser. I also tried with a simple .NET console application and I can access my web services.

Comment: So what is the difference between the client you are trying to use and this simple .NET console app? That kind of client is it? Also, did you run this console app on the server or on another machine? Does it work on both?

Comment: I just solved the problem by searching in the WCF trace. My real client is an Android app. Your first question is very relevant. The only difference between my app and .NET console app is that in my app I had to provide the SOAP action manually (that's what gave me this error (see Edit1 in original post)). btw the .NET console app works on both :)